# Composition of two endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

the question is the following:
Assume two maps where the operator D is defined as

D: $\mathbb{C}\left [ t \right ] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\left [ t \right ], p \rightarrow p'$  and the operator M is defined as

M: $\mathbb{C}\left [ t \right ] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\left [ t \right ], p \rightarrow pt$

I have to show:
$D \circ M - M \circ D = $ Identity Map(id)

If I put the values inside I get
$D \circ M - M \circ D  \\
D \circ (pt)- M \circ (p') \\
p -tp'
$

From here on I don't know how to transform this into the Identity Map

Comment: $D \circ (pt) = (pt)'$, not $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $p \in \mathbb C[t]$. Then
\begin{align*} (D \circ M-M \circ D)(p) &= (D \circ M)(p)-(M \circ D)(p) \\ &= D(M(p)) - M(D(p)) \\ &= D(pt)-M(p') \\ &= (pt)'-p't. \end{align*} Do you see why $(pt)'-p't = p$?

> *Hint*: From the chain rule we see that for any $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb C[t]$, $(fg)' = f'g+fg'$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $D$ is the common derivative, and the second map $M$ is the multiplication by $t$.

Consider a polynomial $p\in \mathbb{C}[t]$, hence
$$(D\circ M-M\circ D)(p(t))=D(tp(t))-M(p^{\prime}(t))=p(t)+tp^{\prime}(t)-tp^{\prime}(t)=p(t)$$

This equalty shows that $D\circ M-M\circ D$ maps any polynomial $p(t)$ to itself. This show that our map is the identity on $\mathbb{C}[t]$ and we are done.